# How to select from a cell in mysql and add to button.text

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2015

i'm a newbie to visual basic 2015 in visual studio community.

what i'm trying to do on load of main form

i have 7 buttons that need the text field changed to correspond with the entries in the Database. these buttons can be change to now categories by the end user down the road.
I'm using MySQL for my database. Any help would be MUCH appreciated as i have searched google and youtube and it's an endless world of OVERLOAD.

My DB Structure is as follows since i cant embed an image:
idbtncat  btn_Name  btn_caption  PanelNo   btn_image
1         btn_cat1  Pizza        pnl_cat1  pizza.jpg

```
Public Class frm_MainConsole
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection

Sub dbconn()
    Dim DatabaseName As String = "posdb"
    Dim server As String = "localhost"
    Dim userName As String = "root"
    Dim password As String = "8943117"
    If Not conn Is Nothing Then conn.Close()
    conn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", server, userName, password, DatabaseName)
    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub frm_MainConsole_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Show()
    dbconn()
    Dim query As String
    Dim command As MySqlCommand
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        dbconn()
        query = "select * from posdb.button_cat where btn_caption"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            btn_Cat1.Text = reader("btn_caption")
            conn.Close()
        End While

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub testDatabaseConnectionToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles testDatabaseConnectionToolStripMenuItem.Click
    If mnit_dbConn.Text = "DB NOT Connected" Then
        dbconn()
        mnit_dbConn.Text = "DB CONNECTED"
    Else
        mnit_dbConn.Text = "DB NOT Connected"
        conn.Close()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: this is your query `select * from posdb.button_cat where btn_caption` ??? check your query first

Comment: i figured it out. now i just have to figure out how to do it in a loop for all 7 buttons.

Comment: Thanks KarthiVenture. it was all in the query like you said.
query = "select btn_caption from button_cat"

Comment: are you fix your problem?

Comment: yes problem was fixed. all but the Loop part for 7 buttons.